# ruby on rails: auto redirect to the home page then perform searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am quite new to rails, and encountered problem when implementing a search bar in my application. This search bar exists in every page of my application, however it only works when I search in the root page. If I click the search button in other pages, the page will not be redirected to home/index and perform search.

Below is my controllers/home_controller.erb (root_path is home#index):

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:display]
      @promos = Promo.where(category: params[:display]).order(created_at: :desc)
    elsif params[:search]
      @promos = Promo.search(params[:search]).order(created_at: :desc)
    else
      @promos = Promo.all.order(created_at: :desc)
    end
  end
end
```

Below is in my view/application.html.erb

```
<form class="search_bar">
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= form_tag(root_path, :method => "get", :controller => "home" ) do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, '', placeholder: "Search Promos", class: "form-control search-input" %>
        <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default") do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> 
        <% end %>
      <% end %>


    </div>
  </form>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? I mainly want to achieve redirecting to the root page and performing the search action. However, if there is any other options of implementing this logic while achieving the same effect, I would be very appreciated to learn that too.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've got a form nested within a form. `<form class="search_bar">` needs to be deleted because it is causing the second form tag, created with `form_tag`, [to be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294730/33226). Your search bar needs to look similar to this:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <%= form_tag(root_path, :method => "get", :controller => "home" ) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, '', placeholder: "Search Promos", class: "form-control search-input" %>
    <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default") do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks very much!